# Fiddler Reissue and Edit and Reissue from composer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler on daily life. However, the most used feature for me, such as `Reissue and Edit` and `Reissue from composer` don't have any shortcuts. I don't know how to use fiddler script for this.  Can anybody point a solution for this?

Comment: I assume you mean shorter than the sequence ContextMenuKey,E,E? (where ALT+Shift+F10 is ContextMenuKey if your keyboard lacks one)?

Comment: The combo is too long for in rapid development :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hit **CTRL+R** to open the FiddlerScript editor.

Inside the **OnBoot()** function add the following code:

```
FiddlerApplication.UI.lvSessions.add_KeyDown(HandleAKey);
```

Immediately after the closing brace for the OnBoot function, add the following code:

```
static function HandleAKey(Sender, theKey:KeyEventArgs) {        
    if (theKey.KeyData == Keys.E)
    {
        var oS: Session = FiddlerApplication.UI.GetFirstSelectedSession();
        if (null == oS) return;
        theKey.Handled = theKey.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        FiddlerApplication.DoComposeByCloning(oS);
    }
}
```

Save the file. Restart Fiddler. Now, when you press the **E** key on any selected session in the Web Sessions list, that session will be cloned to the composer to resend.

Currently, the FiddlerApplication.UI.actReissueSelected() function is not public, which means that there's no simple way to invoke that functionality without calling FiddlerApplication.oProxy.SendRequest() directly.

Comment: Worked Charm! Hope this would be defined feature in upcoming builds.