# Keyboard Shortcut for Editing FiddlerScript?

Tags: fiddler

I want to get to the FiddlerScript editor without using the mouse but I don't see a shortcut for this in https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/Keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Fiddler Reissue and Edit and Reissue from composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068166/fiddler-reissue-and-edit-and-reissue-from-composer):

It's **ctrl+R**.

However, this opens the FiddlerScript editor as a separate window, which isn't exactly the intent of the question, but I find it acceptable for my purposes.